# I'm trying to route the data from flatList into the Modal but I don't know how to use route with Modal between I'm using react native expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false)

  const [name, setName] = React.useState("")
  
  return (
    <View style={style.body}>
      {/*background to style the curve*/}
      <View
        style={{
          ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
          backgroundColor: COLORS.primary
        }}
      />
      {/*View to style the Bottom curve*/}
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: COLORS.gray3,borderTopLeftRadius: SIZES.padding2
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            height: 330,
            marginTop: SIZES.radius,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <FlatList 
            scrollEnabled={false}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            data={donateType}
            keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
            numColumns={2}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    height: 111,
                    width: 180,
                    borderRadius: SIZES.radius2,
                    paddingHorizontal: 4,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center'
                  }}
                  onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
                >
                  <ImageBackground
                    source={item.photo} 
                    resizeMode='cover'
                    style={{
                      height: 100,
                      width: '100%',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                    imageStyle={{ 
                      borderRadius: SIZES.radius    
                    }}
                  >          
                    <Image
                      source={item.icon}
                      style={{
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        marginTop: SIZES.base,
                        tintColor: COLORS.gray3,
                      }}
                    />
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        ...FONTS.h3,
                        color: COLORS.gray3,
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                      }}
                    >
                      {item.name}
                    </Text>
                  </ImageBackground>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Modal Code

```
function renderForm() {
  return (
    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      visible={modalVisible}
      transparent={true}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          marginTop: SIZES.radius,
          backgroundColor: COLORS.gray3,
          borderRadius: SIZES.radius2,
        }}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
          style={{
            padding: SIZES.radius
          }}
        >
          <Image 
            source={icons.cross}
            style={{
              height: 23,
              width: 23,
              tintColor: COLORS.darkGray2
            }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View 
          style={{
            marginTop: -SIZES.radius,
            padding: SIZES.base,
            marginBottom: SIZES.padding
          }}
        >
        <Text
          style={{
            ...FONTS.h2,
            color: COLORS.black,
            fontWeight: '800'
          }}
        >
          Donation Form
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            ...FONTS.body3,
            color: COLORS.gray2,
          }}
        >
          Please fill in the required information..
        </Text>
      </View>
```

When I click on the flat List menu which are 4 menu the Modal is opening and I would like to route the name of the menu that I selected in Modal. I would really appreciated if anyone could please help me out how to route the data into Modal. I was searching several time on different websites I couldn't find proper and clear answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please check this link for how to create a [mcve].  In particular your code has a ton of styling with isn't relevant to your question - could you remove everything that doesn't help answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the name to Modal component as its props

```
const Home = ({navigation}) => {
   const data = [{
      id:1,
      name : 'Ahmad'
   }]
   const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false)
   const [name, setName] = useState("")
   return (
      <View>
         <FlatList data={data} renderItem={({item}) => {
            return <Button title={'item '+item.id} onPress={()=>{setName(item.name);setModalVisible(true)}} />
         }}/>
         {/* Pass name as props to modal component */}
         <RenderForm modalVisible={modalVisible} setModalVisible = {setModalVisible} name={name}/>
      </View>
   );
}
```

Modal Component

```
const RenderForm = ({modalVisible,setModalVisible ,name})=>{
   return(
      <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      visible={modalVisible}
      transparent={true}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          marginTop: SIZES.radius,
          backgroundColor: COLORS.gray3,
          borderRadius: SIZES.radius2,
        }}
      >
         <Text>{name}</Text>
      </View>
   </Modal>
   )
}
```